# summary() gives desired output in R but not Rstudio

Tags: r

When I am typing the `summary` function in R native console it is showing me desired output but when I am using Rstudio it is not.You can see below the output of both. I am using the same data and the same `summary` command so why?

R native console output-

```
Region                 
Midwest  : 30684       
NorthWest: 25939
South    : 41502
west   : 33177

State
California :11570
Texas .    : 7077
Newyork .   : 5595
others     : 94069
```

Rstudio output-

```
Region
Length:131302
Class  : character
Mode .  : Character

State
Length :131302
Class .: character
Mode .  : character
```

Comment: Sorry, i am a newbie. I was using read.csv in R and import dataset option in Rstudio. Using read.csv in Rstudio solves the problem. Thanks for the help Zheyuan and Imo. But do you know why choosing the way i am reading the file causing the problem. Should not import dataset show the same output as i did with read.csv in Rstudio?

Answer (score 2):

The output from the first summary is for factor variables, while the output for the second summary is for character variables.

Here is a reproducible example. This data.frame has two variables, one of which is character and the other of which is a factor. The labels of the factor correspond to the values in the character vector.

```
set.seed(1234)
dat <- data.frame(charVec=sample(state.abb[1:5], 17, replace=TRUE), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
dat$facVec <- factor(dat$charVec)
```

Take a quick look at the structure with `str`

```
str(dat)
'data.frame':   17 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ charVec: chr  "AL" "AR" "AR" "AR" ...
 $ facVec : Factor w/ 5 levels "AK","AL","AR",..: 2 3 3 3 5 3 2 1 3 4 ...
```

Now, run `summary` on this data.frame

```
summary(dat)
   charVec          facVec
 Length:17          AK:4  
 Class :character   AL:2  
 Mode  :character   AR:6  
                    AZ:2  
                    CA:3
```

You most likely used `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` or `as.is=TRUE` your `read.csv` (or similar read function) in the GUI, but did not in rstudio. Or perhaps used data.table's `fread` in rstudio. Using `str` the data.frame in the two sessions will confirm this.